# nib file not opening in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode3to4

I am trying to move from xcode 3.1 to 4.1 and in the process, I installed Xcode 4.1 and opened project I created with Xcode 3.1. But when I build project, it gives error:

The document "filename.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. *** -[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil.

The file is not full screen View with status bar, it is freeform view.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Answer (score 0):

Try this: goto `XCode Menu` => `File` => `Add Files to your-project`, a finder-like browser will pop up. Navigate to your Classes directory. Do you see the filename.xib and can you click on it? Then add it to your project.

Comment: Hi Ott, Thanks for your answer. I can see the file but  unable to click on it. I also tried to remove reference and added file again. but it did not work. Same error occurred.

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupt. xib is just a xml textfile, can you look into it with textedit or such (don't edit it), if you see something strange? Normally it is neatly formatted.

Comment: Thanks ott!! It is normal xml file and no garbage data.. I think I have to recreate the file. There seems no other option.

Comment: Just an update on this... I think that was Xcode problem.. since I installed newer version, it opened without error.

Comment: one more update.... I opened in xcode 4.5 but i could not. finally I installed xcode 3.2.* on other mac, opened the project and open the nib file. Created copy of nib file manually...